# https listener with socket library in php

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

I know about stream_socket_server(), but unfortunately pThreads extension for php do not supports streams and has only wrapper class for socket, which is pretty similar to socket_* lib.

There is the any way to create https listener with socket library in php like:

```
$s = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($s, '127.0.0.1', 443);
socket_listen($s, 0);
socket_set_nonblock($s);

while (true) {
    $c = socket_accept($s);
    /* I need any kind of black magic, which allows to handle secured data from client $c */
}
```

or maybe any other way to works with https?